# NATS Super-Cluster interest propagation

Tags: nats.io

In a NATS cluster, all messages published on one node get sent to all other servers on different nodes. Even if a node has no subscribers for a particular subject, that node still receive all the subject messages.

My use case is such that I need a nats-server to receive messages for a subject ONLY if has any clients subscribed to that subject.

I came across nats interest propagation (https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/configuration/gateways#interest-propagation) which seems to fulfil this requirement. If I can run each node in the cluster as a separate gateway, this should work with Interest-Only mode.

1. Is this understanding correct?
2. I do not find any way to configure this in cluster or gateway.

Has anyone tried this? If yes, could you please let me know how this can be configured?

Thanks.